# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid error in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

**When I'm trying to run my react native app on my Android emulator or device. This error is displayed on the device or emulator.**

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
> built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
> but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the
> file it's defined in. or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

**This is my App.js on the root of the project**

```
 ......
    render() {
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Root>
              <AppRouter />
              <Spinner />
              <NotificationPopup />
              <VersionUpdate />
            </Root>
      </Provider>
        );
    }
........
```

**and this is my package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Nub1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/cookies": "^2.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.5.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.1.4",
    "@unpourtous/react-native-search-list": "^2.0.10",
    "color": "^3.0.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "native-base": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-awesome-card-io": "^0.8.2",
    "react-native-fabric": "0.5.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "0.2.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.25",
    "react-native-mixpanel": "1.2.5",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.7.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.10.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.13",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "react-native-size-matters": "0.1.3",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "1.5.13",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-version-check": "3.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.0.5",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.5",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.0.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.52.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.8",
    "husky": "0.14.3",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.8",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "prettier": "1.5.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know it's a native-base issue or not, as I have also tried NativeBaseProvider instead of Root, as per the forums suggestion but there is no luck at all.

Comment: its hard to detect where the problem, you should commend all component, then just show 1 simple screen, then de-commend one by one component to detect problem.

Comment: Yes, I have done this but I found there is some problem with the Root, as when I removed this. It shows different errors and this error goes

Comment: let try higher libs version.

 "react-navigation": "^4.0.5",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.2",

Comment: Okay @Tim, I will update these, thanks